# Packet does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, variables

After asking my first question and reading some links provided I decided to just and port the communication layer from the open source vb.net project I used for a few months to C#. I started off good. Now I do have a problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Eclipse_5._0
{
    class PacketHandler
    {
        #region Packet Constructors
        private delegate void PacketDelegate(int Index, byte[] Data);
        private PacketDelegate[] Packet;

        public PacketHandler()
        {
            Packet(Enumerations.ClientPackets.CAddChar) = HandleAddChar;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Packet Methods
        public void Handledata(int Index, byte[] Data, int MsgType)
        {
            ByteBuffer Buff = new ByteBuffer();
            Buff.WriteBytes(Data);
            if (MsgType < 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (MsgType >= (int)Enumerations.ClientPackets.CQuit)
            {
                return;
            }
            Packet(MsgType).Invoke(Index, Buff.ReadBytes(Buff.Length()));
            Buff.Dispose();
        }

        public void HandleNewAccount(int Index, byte[] Data)
        {
            //TODO: Add New Player Account File.
        }

        public void HandleAddChar(int Index, byte[] Data)
        {
            //TODO: Add New Character to Player Account File.
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The following line has the error

```
Packet(Enumerations.ClientPackets.CAddChar) = HandleAddChar;
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: What is `Packet` in the line with the error?  Also, what does the compiler error say?

Comment: The convention is to use a lower case letter to start variable names. Doing this will make your code easier for other programmers to read.

Comment: @unholysampler Thanks for the suggestion. Everything I know is pretty much self taught through tutorials on youtube or the web. I guess i picked up some bad habits. I'll start using lower case letters as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Overall, looks like quite a few problems with this code, but if you can post the error details then it might help us help you along a little sooner. Lets looks at maybe getting you passed this hurdle:

`Packet` is an array, so it looks like you want access by index like this:

```
Packet[Enumerations.ClientPackets.CAddChar] = HandleAddChar;
```

But an array is a reference type, and so needs to be instantiated - meaning even with the above in place you'll get a `NullReferenceException`. Furthermore, `HandleAddChar` is a method and requires arguments as per the parameters as part of its definition; and what you're intending to do is not what you would be expressing even with passing the appropriate values. So:

```
public PacketHandler()
{
    Packet = new PacketDelegate[1];        
    Packet[0] = new PacketDelegate(HandleAddChar);
}
```

Note that I've removed use of `Enumerations.ClientPackets.CAddChar` as it is meaningless in this context, the idea is that the array *must* be instantiated and to an appropriate capacity. Lastly, you don't want to call `HandleAddChar` here directly, we need a delegate reference, so that's what we create and insert into the array.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Only thing I'm wondering till I'm able to get home tonight is shouldn't the first packet be 0 and then the packet for handleaddchar be 1?

I still have a lot to learn in C#. Coming from vb6 and vb.net guess doesn't really help. 

I probablly should just learn UPD than try and translate something from vb.net. I guess that would be the best route.

Comment: @cryzone9584: the number `1` in my example is specifying the _length_ of the array (how many `PacketDelegate`'s can fit into it) and the `0` is specifying the _index_ (a certain point within the array that we want to 'put' something.) This is zero-based indexing, see here for differentiation between indexing system: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(computer_science)

Comment: Thanks for the help again. I'll continue this once i finish my last 3 major projects for college. I'll be back and thanks again,